# jQuery code not working in firefox or chrome selector value match mismatch script

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, match, mismatch

This bit of code was helped along by a few folks.  works great in jsFiddle but when I try to run it locally against some live code it fails... I have been working with it for 5 hours and I cannot see what might be missing. I have added the jquery script, the style container and the form/table structure.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
"use strict";

$('#addForm').bind('change', function(evt) {
    $('td.mismatch', this).removeClass('mismatch');

    var selects = $('select', this);
    $(selects).each(function() {
        var that = this;
        $(selects).not(this).each(function() {

            // we have a similar select
            if ($(this).val() !== '' && $(this).val() === $(that).val()) {
                // now compare inputs
                var
                    thisInputs = $('#grouperCost , #casePackForGroups', $(this).closest('tr')),
                    thatInputs = $('#grouperCost , #casePackForGroups', $(that).closest('tr'));

                $(thisInputs).each(function(i) {
                    if ($(this).val() !== $(thatInputs).eq(i).val()) {
                        $(this).closest('td').addClass('mismatch');
                        $(thatInputs).eq(i).closest('td').addClass('mismatch');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
}());
</script>

<style>.mismatch {background: #ff9999;}</style>

<form name="form1" ID="addForm" action="array_script.cfm">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="selectA">
            <option id="A" value="">None</option>
            <option id="A" value="A">A</option>
            <option id="A" value="B">B</option>
            <option id="A" value="C">C</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input ID="grouperCost" type="text" name="price" value="8.99" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input ID="casePackForGroups" type="text" name="perCase" value="4" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="selectB">
            <option id="B" value="">None</option>
            <option id="B" value="A">A</option>
            <option id="B" value="B">B</option>
            <option id="B" value="C">C</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input  ID="grouperCost" type="text" name="price" value="8.98" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input  ID="casePackForGroups" type="text" name="perCase" value="5" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="selectC">
            <option id="C" value="">None</option>
            <option id="C" value="A">A</option>
            <option id="C" value="B">B</option>
            <option id="C" value="C">C</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input  ID="grouperCost" type="text" name="price" value="8.99" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input  ID="casePackForGroups" type="text" name="perCase" value="4" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: do you have the same jquery version?

Comment: Could you paste the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no answer but I found some strange passages in you code.

You Write this:

var selects = $('select', this);//select ALL select + the form element
    $(selects).each(function() { //cycle an all elements

Why do you add the current form to the select collection?

Why do you use 'equality without type coercion' (===) operators? Are they necessary?

Have you tried to debug with firefox 'step by step' ?

Why don't you write a log in a variable or textbox and compare the result with the same code executed on jsFiddle?

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have checked with firebug script error and chrome inspect element.

Comment: I tried many ways but I am unable to have it do anything.  It could be like the one poster said a muddling of versions but it is code that was created today.  The fact that it works in fiddle is peculiar.  What I am trying to do is if your drop downs match.  Look at the price and the case quantity and if there is a mismatch error or do something like highlight it.  That's all, this is for a grouping method I am building of similar products that can be ordered...if there are dupes and the cases and prices match, group them so you just see the one product (to clean up the screen a bit)....